# Remember me functionality in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We are using Worklight 6.1 for our app. I want the app to remember the user id (with no limitation on the duration & it should be accurate & reliable).I want to use JSONStore API for this purpose.

In our app, after we gather the user credentials, we are sending them
to an adaptor function, where we are invoking some java classes to
validate the credentials aginst IBM bluepages & also against dbs

I have two questions:

1) When i ensure that user has been authenticated successfully for the first time, I will open a JSON store & keep the userid to the local storage, If I choose to encrypt it , which password I need to supply to make it encrypted ?

2) When the user tries to access the app from the same mobile device, the server should send a login form by pre populating the user id, how do I do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypted Offline Cache is deprecated, so you might as well use JSONStore.

In MobileFirst Platform 6.3 ("Worklight"), there is a tutorial that accomplishes exactly your scenario. You should read it and try to implement it in 6.1; depending on JSONStore's featureset in 6.1, you might be able to. You'll need to try.

Here it is: [Offline Authentication](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/offline-authentication/)

Comment: Idan, I had a chance to look at a solution implemented by Encryption cache for 'Remember me'. It looks very simple. "Encrypted Offline Cache" is it different from Encryption cache ? And also, is there a chance that the data we store can be deleted in the case of encryption cache ?

Comment: Encrypted Cache == Encrypted Offline Cache; It's based on HTML5 Storage; use JSONStore.